# Syntax Error in Join Operation - MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax-error, vba

I'm trying to finish the below query but I keep getting a syntax error in JOIN operation in the SELECT portion. I'm fairly green in this space so if you can help, I'd appreciate it. I've looked at other questions posted here but haven't gotten any answers.

```
SELECT [tblUSReqOutput.*], 
[tblUSReqOutput].[Job State],
[tblUSReqs].[Ever in Status Applicant - Review Resume: Hiring Manager Review], 
[tblUSReqs].[Currently in Status Applicant - Review Resume: Hiring Manager Re], 
[tblUSReqs].[Ever in Status Candidate - Interview Process: Phone Screen], 
[tblUSReqs].[# Currently in Status Candidate - Interview Process: Schedule Ph], 
[tblUSReqs}.[# Currently in Status Candidate - Interview Process: Phone Scree], 
[tblUSReqs].[# Ever in Status Candidate - Interview Process: Interview], 
[tblUSReqs].[# Currently in Status Candidate - Interview Process: Schedule In], 
[tblUSReqs].[# Currently in Status Candidate - Interview Process: Interview], 
[tblUSReqs].[# Ever in Bin Candidate - Offer], 
[tblUSReqs].[# Currently in Bin Candidate - Offer], 
[tblUSReqs].[# Ever in Bin Candidate - Pre-hire], 
[tblUSReqs].[# Ever in Bin Employee], tblUSReqs.[# Ever in Bin Rejected], 
[tblUSReqs].[# of Openings], tblUSReqs.[# of Openings Remaining], 
[tblUSReqs].[# Currently in Status Candidate - Offer: Accepted], 
[tblUSReqs].[# Currently in Status Candidate - Pre-hire: Prepare for Hire], 
[tblUSReqs].[# Currently in Status Candidate - Offer: Extended], 
[tblUSHRorgchart].[Org Chart Level 02 Name] AS HROrgL2, 
[tblUSHRorgchart].[Org Chart Level 04 Name] AS HROrgL3, 
[tblUSHRorgchart].[Org Chart Level 05 Name] AS HROrgL4,
[tblUSHRorgchart].[Org Chart Level 05 Name] AS HROrgL5, 
[tblUSHRorgchart].[Org Chart Level 06 Name] AS HROrgL6, 
[tblUSHRorgchart].[Org Chart Level 07 Name] AS HRorgL7, 
[tblUSPrehires].[Person : Source - Category], 
[tblUSPrehires].[Person : Applicant Type], 
[tblUSPrehires].[Step], 
[tblUSPrehires].[Last Applicant - Applied], 
[tblUSPrehires].[Last Applicant - Review Resume], 
[tblUSPrehires].[Last Candidate - Interview Process], 
[tblUSPrehires].[Last Candidate - Offer], 
[tblUSPrehires].[Last Candidate - Pre-hire], 
[tblUSPrehires].[Last Employee],
Coalesce([Person : Source - Category],"No Source") AS [Source Category], 
Coalesce([Source],"No Source") AS [Hire Source], 
[Last Candidate - Pre-hire: Prepare for Hire]+7-Weekday([Last Candidate - Pre-hire: Prepare for Hire],2) AS [Pre-Hire Confirmed Weekending], 
Year([Last Candidate - Pre-hire: Prepare for Hire]) AS [Pre-Hire Year], 
Month([Last Candidate - Pre-hire: Prepare for Hire]) AS [Pre- Hire Month], 
[tblUSReqs].[Req Status], 
[tblUSPreHires].[Person : Full Name: Last, First], 
[qryApplicant numbers].[CountOfJob : AM Req ID] AS [# 2013Applicants], 
[tblUSReqs].[# Ever in Bin Employee], 
[tblUSReqs].[# of Openings Remaining]

FROM (tblUSReqOutput LEFT JOIN tblUSHRorgchart ON tblUSReqs.[Job Recruiter Login]) = tblUSHROrgchart.[Employee User ID] 
LEFT JOIN (tblUSReqs ON tblUSReqOutput.[ICIMS ID] = tblUSReqs.[AMZR Req ID] 
LEFT JOIN tblUSPrehires ON tblUSReqOutput.[ICIMS ID] = tblUSPreHires.[Job : AMZR Req ID]) 
LEFT JOIN TblSource ON tblUSPrehires.[Person : Source - Category] = TblSource.[Source Category]) 
LEFT JOIN [qryApplicant numbers] ON tblUSReqOutput.[ICIMS ID] = [qryApplicant numbers].[Job : AMZR Req ID])

WHERE ([tblUSReqOutput].[Job State]) Like "Eliminated") 
AND ([tblUSHRorgchart].[Org Chart Level 04 Name]) Is Not Null) 
AND ([tblUSPrehires].[Person : Full Name: Last, First]) Is Not Null) 
AND ([tblUSReqOutput].Approved)="Y")) 
OR ([tblUSReqOutput].[Org Chart Level 04 Name]) Is Not Null) 
AND ([tblUSReqs].[Req Status]) Like "eliminate*")
AND ([tblUSPreHires].[Person : Full Name: Last, First]) Is Not Null) 
AND ([tblUSReqOutput].[Approved])="Y")
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like  mismatched parenthesis

```
FROM (tblUSReqOutput LEFT JOIN tblUSHRorgchart ON tblUSReqs.[Job Recruiter Login]) = tblUSHROrgchart.[Employee User ID] 
LEFT JOIN (tblUSReqs ON tblUSReqOutput.[ICIMS ID] = tblUSReqs.[AMZR Req ID] 
LEFT JOIN tblUSPrehires ON tblUSReqOutput.[ICIMS ID] = tblUSPreHires.[Job : AMZR Req ID]) 
LEFT JOIN TblSource ON tblUSPrehires.[Person : Source - Category] = TblSource.[Source Category]) 
LEFT JOIN [qryApplicant numbers] ON tblUSReqOutput.[ICIMS ID] = [qryApplicant numbers].[Job : AMZR Req ID])
```

1st & 2nd lines have opening parens but no close

3rd, 4th & 5th lines have no opening parens, but do have closing parens

So they're mismatched in total and inconsistently applied

Comment: And I see in line 7 there's a `}` that should be a `]`.